# Refactor lua table - neovim configuration

Tags: lua, lua-table, neovim

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your input. I use lua for the formatter plugin configuration, the following code is my current configuration.

```
require('formatter').setup({
  filetype = {
    javascript = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    typescriptreact = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    javascriptreact = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    html = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    css = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    json = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    php = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    vue = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
    svelte = {
      -- prettier
      function()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end
    },
  }
})
```

As you will notice the function inside the table is repeated many times, to refactor this code try the following:

```
function config()
        return {
          exe = "prettier",
          args = {"--stdin-filepath", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)), '--single-quote'},
          stdin = true
        }
      end

require('formatter').setup({
  filetype = {
    javascript = {
      -- prettier
     config()
      
    },
  }
})
```

However, that code gives me an error, I'm new to lua. I appreciate your help in refactoring this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the first element of each language table should be a function (or something callable), not the table that calling this function returns.

```lua
require('formatter').setup({
  filetype = {
    javascript = { config },
  }
})
```

Comment: that's it, thanks